# Python Flask & HTML Local Variables in Python (UnboundLocalError)

Tags: python, html, parsing, variables, local-variables

I am using Python Flask to host a web server which mostly works. I understand the problem but I do not know how to work around it. I understand that within the code shown, when the website first launches it renders the template and the variable "CurtainCloseTime" has no assigned value. So I have 2 forms on my website where I enter a time for the curtains to close and open hence the variable names. The Variable "CCT" means CurtainCloseTime and is the variable within the HTML file because I want it to display back to the web page.

Here is the Python Flask Code:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST': #If there is an input from form
        CurtainOpenTime = request.form['CurtainOpenTime'] #Assign CurtainOpenTime variable in python to the html CurtainOpenTime variable.
        CurtainCloseTime = request.form['CurtainCloseTime'] #Assign CurtainCloseTime variable in python to the html CurtainCloseTime variable.

    return render_template('Index.html',  CCT=CurtainCloseTime)
```

Comment: So what happens when `request.method` is **not** set to `'POST'`? What should be rendered in that case?

Comment: I have fixed the indentation, it was because I had to rewrite the code rather than copy and paste. When I set request.method == 'GET' so not POST, I get 400 Bad Request error.

Comment: I didn't suggest you change the test, I am asking you to think through what should happen in the `'GET'` case. The variable `CurtainCloseTime` is only *set* when you are receiving a `'POST'` method request. You get the error because you don't set it in the `'GET'` case.

Comment: So how would I set it in the GET case?

Comment: I don't know, you haven't told us anything about what the route should *do* when accessed with a `GET`. You need to think this through, not us. All I can do is tell you why you get your error.

Comment: alright, thank you I'll go do some research and thank you because you helped verify what the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you have an indentation problem in your question. I suppose that your actual code is :

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST': #If there is an input from form
        CurtainOpenTime = request.form['CurtainOpenTime'] # CurtainOpenTime variable in python to the html CurtainOpenTime variable.
        CurtainCloseTime = request.form['CurtainCloseTime'] #Assign CurtainCloseTime variable in python to the html CurtainCloseTime variable.

    return render_template('Index.html',  CCT=CurtainCloseTime)
```

If that is your code (but we cannot be sure), then if the http method is 'GET', CCT has no value. You have to specify it outside of the 'if' statement :

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    CurtainCloseTime = # define a default value here

    if request.method == 'POST': #If there is an input from form
        CurtainOpenTime = request.form['CurtainOpenTime'] # CurtainOpenTime variable in python to the html CurtainOpenTime variable.
        CurtainCloseTime = request.form['CurtainCloseTime'] #Assign CurtainCloseTime variable in python to the html CurtainCloseTime variable.

    return render_template('Index.html',  CCT=CurtainCloseTime)
```

Comment: Yes sorry about the indentation what you have posted is correct, I had to rewrite the code from my Raspberry pi to my other computer I am using to post this. So how would I go about assigning CCT's value outside of the request.method if statement?

Comment: Just the way I wrote the second block of code. Before (or after) the 'if'. So everything outside the 'if' will be executed if you call the route with the 'GET' method, and everything inside the 'if' will be executed when you call the 'POST' method (with a form typically).